# Multiple table query not working on certain databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, parameters

I have 12 locations each running their own database.  Each database is setup exactly the same, with their own information.  The databases are all SQL2005 or 2008 server.  I wrote a multiple table query to pull information for paying commission on sales.  This query works on 10 of the 12 databases, the other 2 databases do not return any results.  If I run the query with 2 joined tables (on the 2 databases it does not work on) it works, however the other tables in question have nothing to do with the "where" statement.  Could anyone shed some light on why it would not work on 2 of the 2005 server databases if it works on all of the others?  My Code is:

```
SELECT        Customers.sBarcode AS Barcode, Customers.dtCreated AS Created, CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sCreatedBy AS [Commission pays], 
                         Surcharges.sDescription AS [Unlimited Package], Surcharges.dblCommission AS [Commission Amount], Users.sUserName AS Greeter, @startdate AS Start_Date, 
                         @enddate AS End_Date
FROM            CustomerUnlimitedTransactions INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lCustomerId = Customers.lCustomerID INNER JOIN
                         VIPAccountTypes ON CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lMonthlyAccountTypeId = VIPAccountTypes.lAccountType INNER JOIN
                         Surcharges ON VIPAccountTypes.lSurchargeId = Surcharges.Surcharge_ID INNER JOIN
                         Users ON Customers.lGreeterID = Users.ID_User
WHERE        (Customers.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND 
                         (CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sTransactionType = N'sale') AND (CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lMonthlyAccountTypeId = '11') OR
                         (Customers.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND 
                         (CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sTransactionType = N'sale') AND (CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lMonthlyAccountTypeId = '12')
ORDER BY Created
```

If I run the query like this I still do not return any results:

```
SELECT        Customers.sBarcode AS Barcode, Customers.dtCreated AS Created, CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sCreatedBy AS [Commission pays], 
                             Surcharges.sDescription AS [Unlimited Package], Surcharges.dblCommission AS [Commission Amount], Users.sUserName AS Greeter, @startdate AS Start_Date, 
                             @enddate AS End_Date
    FROM            CustomerUnlimitedTransactions INNER JOIN
                             Customers ON CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lCustomerId = Customers.lCustomerID INNER JOIN
                             VIPAccountTypes ON CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lMonthlyAccountTypeId = VIPAccountTypes.lAccountType INNER JOIN
                             Surcharges ON VIPAccountTypes.lSurchargeId = Surcharges.Surcharge_ID INNER JOIN
                             Users ON Customers.lGreeterID = Users.ID_User
    WHERE        (Customers.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102))
    ORDER BY Created
```

If I run the query like this I DO get results:

```
SELECT        Customers.sBarcode AS Barcode, Customers.dtCreated AS Created, CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sCreatedBy AS [Commission pays], 
                                 Surcharges.sDescription AS [Unlimited Package], Surcharges.dblCommission AS [Commission Amount], Users.sUserName AS Greeter, @startdate AS Start_Date, 
                                 @enddate AS End_Date
        FROM            CustomerUnlimitedTransactions INNER JOIN
                                 Customers ON CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lCustomerId = Customers.lCustomerID 
        WHERE        (Customers.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102))
        ORDER BY Created
```

There are not any Null's associated with any of the above query's.  Again this works on 10 of 12... and yes the databases are EXACTLY the same.  (if I run this query out for a year date range I get results) however I should show 25 results from last week alone, and I am showing none on each of the 2.

Comment: Engage wild guess mode. Make sure The servers are set up the same. Different locale and my long time favourite case sensitive collation in master (and therefore tempdb). Incorrect compatibility mode can be good for a laugh on occasion as well.

Comment: @Shmewnix "If I run the query with 2 joined tables (on the 2 databases it does not work on) it works" Can you elaborate/show the query that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint: the IN keyword works wonders for your WHERE clause

```
WHERE Customers.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102)
                              AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)
  AND CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.sTransactionType = N'sale'
  AND CustomerUnlimitedTransactions.lMonthlyAccountTypeId in ('11',12)
```

As for WHERE clause not affecting the other tables in the JOIN, I highly suspect you need to turn them from INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs.

As written (hint #2: please use sensible aliases *liberally*)

```
      FROM CustomerUnlimitedTransactions T
INNER JOIN Customers C ON T.lCustomerId = C.lCustomerID
INNER JOIN VIPAccountTypes V ON T.lMonthlyAccountTypeId = V.lAccountType
INNER JOIN Surcharges S ON V.lSurchargeId = S.Surcharge_ID
INNER JOIN Users U ON C.lGreeterID = U.ID_User
```

For a row to appear in the final result, the customer would have to have at least one transaction of a VIP Account type involving sucharges, and he must have be greeted (loose reading of joins). Any nulls along the JOINs and the row disappears.

Comment: Again, what is suspicious here is it works on 10 of 12 databases... I suppose the question is why does it matter on these specific databases weather it's Inner or Left join?  See Edit above for what else does not work.

Comment: There were indeed Null's in the results.  I missed one step in this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are in fact identical (see comment from Tony Hopkinson), then look at the fields you're doing a `JOIN` on to see if there are any null values.

Comment: See above post.  I have checked for null's.  There are not any nulls that exist.